# Построить таблицу в oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Подскажите как можно построить данную таблицу

Наименование (КО №1)  - берется с табл `t_mo` поле `mo` , без одинаковых названий

Наименование2 (МО) – берется с табл `t_pet` поле `otv_kon`

Формат (пусто) – в этом столбце будет всегда пусто

Формат2 (1) – значение `const`

Принято(0)

```
select count(*) 
from t_block t, t_pet p, t_mo w 
where t.id_ger=p.id 
  and p.mo_id=w.mo_id 
  and p.conect_id=5 
  and to_date(t.date_end) between to_date('01.03.2019') and to_date('31.03.2019')
  and p.mo_id =10 
  and p.otv_kon=54001
```

Принято(44)

```
select count(*) 
from t_block t, t_pet p, t_mo w 
where t.id_ger=p.id 
  and p.mo_id=w.mo_id 
  and p.conect_id=5 
  and to_date(t.date_end) between to_date('01.03.2019') and to_date('31.03.2019')
  and p.mo_id =12 
  and p.otv_kon=54001
```

Закрыто(0)

```
select count(*) 
from t_block t, t_pet p, t_mo w 
where t.id_ger=p.id 
  and p.mo_id=w.mo_id 
  and p.conect_id=5 
  and to_date(t.date_end) between to_date('01.03.2019') and to_date('31.03.2019')
  and p.mo_id =10 
  and p.otv_kon=54001 
  and p.cause in (22,1)
```

Закрыто(44)

```
select count(*) 
from t_block t, t_pet p, t_mo w 
  where t.id_ger=p.id 
  and p.mo_id=w.mo_id 
  and p.conect_id=5 
  and to_date(t.date_end) between to_date('01.03.2019') and to_date('31.03.2019')
  and p.mo_id =12 
  and p.otv_kon=54001 
  and p.cause in (22,1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t_mo.mo, 
       t_pet.otv_kon, 
       '', 
       1, 
       COUNT(*), 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p.cause IN (22,1) THEN 1 END)
FROM t_block t, t_pet p, t_mo w 
  WHERE t.id_ger=p.id 
  AND p.mo_id=w.mo_id 
  AND p.conect_id=5 
  AND to_date(t.date_end) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.03.2019') AND TO_DATE('31.03.2019')
  AND p.mo_id =12 
  AND p.otv_kon=54001
```

?

Comment: Выходит ошибка  - ORA-00907 Отсутствует правая скобка

Comment: @wq55 Проверьте ещё разок...